# Add video to Media Web Part from Firefox

Tags: firefox, sharepoint-2010

In my page in edit mode, when i select the Media Web Part, in Firefox, the options in the Media Options toolbar are all grayed out.

Is there a way to make this work in Firefox?

Here is the complete scenario: 
I have a page with a RichHtmlField Web Part, I edit the page, using the Editing Tools Insert toolbar, I Select 'Video and Audio' which insert a Media Web Part.
Then when i select the web part to add a video to it, the options are grayed in Firefox.

Everything works fine with the same user in Internet Explorer...

Any help or link mentionning this is not working in Firefox

Thanx

**UPDATE**

I found this [Sharepoint 2010 Video Publishing Site Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/6e47cfbd-cd09-4b1f-88bf-e7c5868dae8e) but i'd need something more official to show our client. Anyone has something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use firefox amatur mistake.... sharepoint 2007 used to HATE and i repeat HATE firefox, 2010 is much better i obviously got carried away thinking everything was perfect in 2010 using firefox

from [Sharepoint 2010 Video Publishing Site Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/6e47cfbd-cd09-4b1f-88bf-e7c5868dae8e), marked as answer by [Rock Wang– MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/rock%20wang%E2%80%93%20msft/)